# Jenkins+Sonar (War) Driver JDBC not found

Tags: jdbc, jenkins, driver, sonarqube

I have a CI with Jenkins, I install Sonar on my Tomcat 7, I downloaded Sonar and change the sonar.properties to use oracle (I have oracle 10g). I deploy the war with no errors, the app works and it created the tables. When i tried to use Sonar from Jenkins ina a job it execute a Maven command (I have maven 3.0.1 configured:I Have Redhat EL 5.). the command generated is:

**mvn -f /root/.jenkins/jobs/ProjectTestSonar/workspace/ProjectSonar/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin@192.168.74.14:1521:dbs10g  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:8080/sonar**

The error is:

**[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project salida:
Can not execute Sonar: Fail to connect to database: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
for connect URL 'jdbc:oracle:thin@192.168.74.14:1521:dbs10g': No suitable driver ->
[Help 1]** org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar
(default-cli) on project salida: Can not execute Sonar at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver class is oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver but not oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver in the recent versions of the Oracle JDBC driver.